# minSdk != deviceSdk

Tags: android, android-studio

I just recently started getting into Android development. I feel this is a very stupid question but I'll shoot anyway since I've spent an hour on this already. I am currently trying to run a project on my device, with no changes to what Android Studio gave me. I think this image should describe my problem better:

[image]

When running I get `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`.

I can't understand why they are not compatible. Rather, why does `minSdk` say API 20 when `minSdkVersion` on build.gradle says 15? I've tried adding `uses-sdk` on manifest.xml but I figured that would be unnecessary since my build.gradle file will overwrite that (it didn't work also).

Am I missing some kind of setting here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, using 'L' as the `targetSdkVersion` makes it so the `minSdkVersion` is ignored. You should set the `targetSdkVersion` to something other than `L`.

Comment: I tried making it to 19 but I get the same output. I've made sure to sync my project with the gradle files also.

Comment: Also change your `compileSdkVersion` to `19`. Note that this may require you to download the appropriate SDK Platform entry in the SDK Manager.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a bug. It's a feature :).

> If you compile against a preview platform, you can only run on a
>   preview platform.

You should set `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion` to API `19`.

You can read more about this problem here:

[Issue 72617: Android Studio Compatible: No, minSdk(API 20, Lpreview) != deviceSdk(API 19)](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72617)

[Issue 72453:   Setting sdkCompileVersion to 'android-L' creates an apk with 'L' as minSdk regardless of a lower minSdkVersion value](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72453)

Comment: Same requirement coming up now that 'android-N' is out.