# Android device API level does not match version

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

After updating my android phone version from **4.1.2 (API 16)** to **5.0.2 (API 21)** my device API level is still remaining at 16 while the version is 5.0.2. Below text is shown when trying to run an application inside Android Studio:

> Samsung GT-S7262 (Android 5.0.2, API 16) (minSdk(API 21) >
>   deviceSdk(API 16))

Here is the screen shot:
[image]

I used the following link instructions to update my android device:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-star/general/lollipop-gt-s7262-samsung-galaxy-star-t3140853

Comment: Do you have the latest drivers for that phone installed?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845950/minsdk-devicesdk

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633271/android-error-no-minsdkapi-19-devicesdkapi-1

Comment: and post build.grandle

Comment: I have already read those posts. That didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I could have changed the minSdkVersion in build.gradle, but I built my app for API 21. that is why I updated my phone to 5.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the link again. It is written above "Lollipop Themed Rom" not real lollipop. That is why it is showing API 16.

Comment: that rom is truly just a Themed Lollipop ROM with a "hard written" version code. the answer should be accepted